# Installing git on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 with git bash for Windows already installed?

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using the git bash shell on Windows 10 for a while, but I only just installed the WSL/Bash for Ubuntu on Windows. BUW has an entire file system separate from my Windows files, and also its own packages. 
So question: If I install git on BUW (using `apt-get install git`), is that just redundant (so I should stick with the git bash shell I already have and know), or is it the BUW version better in some way (and I should uninstall git as I have it now)? If I install both, will they conflict?
(Keeping in mind that I use git on my Windows files - not at all sure whether that'll still work if I uninstall git bash, honestly.)

Comment: What do you mean you use it on your Windows file? The difference would be whatever the difference between the Windows and Linux version would be. You could use both at the same time. If there is normal PATH integration for tools installed by Ubuntu on Windows you might run into issues if you checked that box during the GIT Windows setup. In that case it should be taking the first executable on the path it finds if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing git on WSL and installing git on windows is different. There won't be any conflict. The environment variables of WSL and Windows are separate. Changes made to env on WSL doesn't affect the env on Windows. Both versions of git are almost same so no comparison regarding that. You can definitely run them simultaneously on both system and it will never create any conflict. Both works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I've learned since I asked this question that there are some problems with line endings (Git for Windows converts to CRLF because that's what I set it to when I installed it). But otherwise, that answers my question.

Comment: So if I `add` and/or `commit` changes  in a Windows git folder (not a folder inside mnt/c WSL) from PS or Windows Git Bash (which I assume both would use the Windows git installation) and then continue adding and or committing or whatever with the Ubuntu WSL git installation, there won't be any problem at all either? Is that totally safe too?

Comment: It should be safe too.